# How to have a generic type inherit from a generic type

Tags: templates, c#-3.0

I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class LMManager<ENTITY, ILM_ENTITY> where ENTITY : ILM_ENTITY, IActiveRecord, ICallOnCreated, new( )
```

ENTITY is some kind of DataObject, ILM_ENTITY, IActiveRecord, and ICallOnCreated are interfaces that the DataObject implements.

Typically, I subclass this guy with classes something like

```
public class JobManager : LMManager<Job, ILMJob>
public class JobViewManager : LMManager<vwJob, ILMJobView>
```

Now, I have a case where two of the sub-classes have some code in common, so I want to insert another layer in between, something like

```
public abstract class JobManagerBase : LMManager<ENTITY, ILM_ENTITY>
```

and then change the other two guys to

```
public class JobManager : JobManagerBase<Job, ILMJob>
public class JobViewManager : JobManagerBase<vwJob, ILMJobView>
```

In the definition of my JobManagerBase, I get four errors related to ENTITY:

1. Must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor
2. No boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from ENTITY to ICallOnCreated
3. No boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from ENTITY to IActiveRecord
4. No boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from ENTITY to ILM_ENTITY

Is it terribly obvious what I am missing?

Comment: Don't use all-caps.  Also, generic parameters should start with `T`.

Comment: Do you mean `JobManagerBase<ENTITY, ILM_ENTITY> : LMManager<ENTITY, ILM_ENTITY>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `JobManagerBase` attempts to use `LMManager` with the parameters `ENTITY` and `ILM_ENTITY`.
Since these parameters do not meet your constraints, you get an error.  (What if someone makes a `JobManagerBase<int, string>`?)

You need to add generic parameters and the same `where` clause to `JobManagerBase` to ensure that its parameters meet the constraints required for `LMManager`.